# Which solution is better? To have expanded tables for paths or one table?

Tags: database, database-design

Database Design:

[image]

This is my simple database design, what would I like to know is which solution is better among the two. Solution 1 have each table for each dimension like 1366x768 dimension table and stores the path for specific dimension, and in Solution 2 there is a table which stores a generic path (which contains like sub folders) and the dimensions table stores the dimensions and to retrieve the images concatenation can be used. So which you think is better among the two, like easy to implement, less complicated..something like that..?

Comment: I suggest you study carefully the type of information you want out of the database. In BI this makes all the difference. Both of your solution tend to resemble a "snow-flake" rather than a pure "star" schema.

Comment: just need to retrieve images with some information associated with them..its just the storing thingy I would like to understand since I think that is the foundation of my database..

Comment: The answer requires some thinking...Note that I am not sure if the relationship between "walls" and "desktop_wall" is correct or not...

Comment: oh I need to update the desktop_id to wall_id in solution 2..if that's what you are saying..

Answer (score 1):

Using Solution 1, if new resolutions appear, you'd be adding a new tables.  Using Solution 2, you'd be adding new records.

It may not be quite so easy to design and implement Solution 2, but it will result in a simpler database with fewer tables

Comment: was thinking something similar..two more questions, which is better? simpler database or lot of tables? and is this somehow a good design? I know there could be improvements but from the basics..would this be good? thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing all the details (what do you normally update, which data changes, what may be extended in the future?) I would go for solution 2.

Solution 1 seems overcomplicated - there's a lot of tables to manage. I can't see a problem with basic operations you might do in solution 2 and simplicity and clarity of design is always a plus.

Having many records in one table is not normally a problem - database systems are designed to handle that very well.

Comment: I'll normally be updating paths..regarding adding things later would be the sizes I guess..

Comment: So if paths always consist of those 2 parts, it's easy to update them in solution 2. Same for adding me sizes - you need to add 1 record instead of new table.

Comment: the path would be necessarily consisting two parts (1366x768, 1280x800) sometimes just one..so what I was thinking like all the paths for one size could be in one table I think that would help filtering records faster than solution 2..what you say?

Comment: It could force you to write `IF` statements in your queries to read from different tables which is bad for performance (problems with execution plans). With the right indexes, solution 2 will be fast.